# jQuery qtip() - how to get the id from mouseover, .$load()

Tags: jquery, qtip

I have the Jquery qtip() function and i need to get the id when mouseover a link. Can i'm using jquery .load() to get the page. Cant able to get using below code. Anyone know?

Below is my script

```
$(function () {
      $(".cabinlink").qtip({
content: $("#loadCabin").load("/mysite ." + $(this).attr('id')),

                 show: 'mouseover',
                 hide: 'mouseout',

                 style: {
                     width: 780
                 },
                 position: {
                     corner: {
                         target: 'LeftBottom',
                         tooltip: 'TopLeft'
                     }
                 }
             });
         });
```

.cabinlink is the mousehover link

```
<a id="1" href="javascript:void(0)" class="cabinlink" />
<a id="2" href="javascript:void(0)" class="cabinlink" />
<a id="3" href="javascript:void(0)" class="cabinlink" />
```

loadCabin is the div to open up the qtip box

```
<div id="loadCabin"></div>
```

Amended codes, able to work but need to mouse over two times. first mouseover no result. Anyone know?

```
 $(function () {
         $(".cabinlink").live('mouseover', function () {

             var id = $(this).attr('id');
             var url = "/Mysite ." + id;
             $(this).qtip({
                 overwrite: false,
                 content: $("#loadCabin").load(url),
                 show: { ready: true, when: false },
                 hide: 'mouseout',
                 style: {
                     width: 780
                 },
                 position: {
                     corner: {
                         target: 'LeftBottom',
                         tooltip: 'TopLeft'
                     }
                 }

             });
         });

     });
```

Comment: IDs can't start with numbers.

Comment: I don't know the qtip API well enough to answer your question, but I can tell you that you're not getting the ID where you expect because "this" is referring to the options object you're passing to qtip, not to the element that was hovered over. I imagine that one of the options to qtip lets you pass a callback function from which your call to $(this).attr('id') would return the element's ID as you expect.

Comment: In addition to that, you need to consider the timing...$(".cabinlink").qtip(...) runs as soon as the page loads, and just tells it to initialize with the given options. Later, hover events are handled by qtip, and it's only then that you'd even know which element was hovered over.

Comment: @Blender It's indeed best to avoid IDs starting with numbers (only HTML5 allows them and they still should be avoided), but that's not what's causing the problem here

Comment: @MattB.: Huh, I didn't know that changed in HTML5. Thanks.

Comment: @Blender Truth be told I just found out myself. Your comment prompted me to look it up since I had never had an urge to begin an ID with a number and wasn't aware of the rule. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: BTW the live() method is deprecated. Use on() instead: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".cabinlink").qtip({
    onShow: function() {
        $("#loadCabin").load("/mysite." + $(this).attr('id'))
    },

     show: 'mouseover',
     hide: 'mouseout',

     style: {
         width: 780
     },
     position: {
         corner: {
             target: 'LeftBottom',
             tooltip: 'TopLeft'
         }
     }
 });
```

If that doesn't work, one of the other callback functions may...see http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/api/#callbacks

Comment: can't able to get it work on your codes. I have amended the codes as above, It seems to work that ways, but problem now is i need to mouseover two time this time. First mouseover doesn't appear anything. Any Idea

Comment: It looks like you may need to handle the mouseover event yourself and then use the updateContent method of the qtip API as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879907/jquery-ajax-and-qtip-dynamic-content. Note that you'll need to use the $.get or $.ajax method rather than $.load to use this approach.

Comment: Actually I think your situation is different from the one in the link; there may be an easier solution, I'll post back here if I think of it.

Comment: Forget my previous comments (you don't need your own mouseover() handler); try this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2297936/560114 (note that I linked to a specific answer; the accepted answer of that question is incorrect).